# Unable to compile swift file in Visual Studio code and Windows 10

Tags: swift, typescript, visual-studio-code, windows-10

What I am trying to do is use Visual Studio code to compile a swift language code that I am trying to run but unfortunately I am getting an error with tasks.json file

> error TS6054: File 'section-1.swift' must have extension '.ts' or
>   '.d.ts'.

I have followed the steps as mentioned by David Owens II http://owensd.io/2015/05/21/swift-vscode.html and also referenced older stuff from Stack Overflow and installed Typescript from npm command prompt and modified Tasks.json file as shown below

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc.
    "command": "swiftc",

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur. 
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // Under windows use tsc.exe. This ensures we don't need a shell.
    "windows": {
        "command": "tsc.cmd"
    },

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": ["section-1.swift"],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": {
        "pattern": {
            "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
            "file": 1,
            "line": 2,
            "column": 3,
            "severity": 4,
            "message": 5
        }
    }
}
```

My question in here is as my file is a swift file how would I convert it to .ts file as this is causing the error?Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: That article is for compiling Swift on a Mac with XCode installed. As far as I can tell, it probably won't compile on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like VSCode is trying to execute the file as if it were a TS file, and not a swift file.  Perhaps it's the following lines?

```
// Under windows use tsc.exe. This ensures we don't need a shell.
"windows": {
    "command": "tsc.cmd"
},
```

I know you're not on windows, but VSCode could be confused by this line, vs the other line.  Perhaps just try changing it to swift.cmd, or removing the section entirely.

Comment: I have removed the section but it didn't help.

Comment: adding swift.cmd is not helping either.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a swift compiler installed on your computer? Try it from the command prompt (`Ctrl+Shift+C`): `where swiftc`

Comment: Since you are on Windows you would have to install a Swift compiler for Windows (maybe "Silver"?), and replace "tsc.cmd" in the windows section with the path of the Swift compiler.